# Where is your personal macro workbook located?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for the Excel file where my personal macro workbook is stored. Does anyone know where that file might be on a Windows 7 computer?

Comment: your question is pretty unclear to me.

Comment: @UGP--it's crystal clear, if you know the name of said workbook is `personal.xlsb` or if you Googlle `Where is your personal macro workbook located?`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer. You can find the file PERSONAL.XLSB by using the code below.

```
Sub Find_Personal_Macro_Workbook()

    Dim path As String

    path = Application.StartupPath

    MsgBox path

End Sub
```

Hidden items will need to be selected in your file explorer to see where this is.

Hope this helps anyone who needs to find this file.

Comment: Thanks! This shows how to find the FOLDER XLStart, which is where `personal.xlsb` SHOULD be. *But what if it's not there?*

Comment: *D'OH!* Then CREATE it. You don't HAVE one.

Comment: (GOOD ANSWER!!)

Comment: This is a good answer, but it needs a Debug.Print or something like @dzozo's answer so you can easily go where it tells you.

Comment: This is the right answers as it (still) works for both Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 20):

In this folder:
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

(Hidden Items needs to be selected in your files explorer)

If you don't have a Roaming folder use the Local folder. Rest of the path should be the same.

Comment: In Windows 10 you can go here with `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps:
1. Open Excel 
2. Unhide Personal Workbook from View->Unhide
3. Press F12 to locate the path of the workbook.

Comment: `personal.xlsb` is not mentioned in the `View` menu. And what does `F12` do to find `personal.xlsb`?

Comment: These instructions make no sense in Outlook 2016, at least.

Comment: Definitely not in Outlook, but neither do they make sense for Excel. Most likely the answer should be that no PERSONAL.XLSB exists by default, so you are not going to find it. It must be created by user macro activities, and then the "how to locate" tips will bear fruit.

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on swridings answer and have it paste that path to a cell so you can copy and paste it into the explorer, see below:

```
Sub Find_Personal_Macro_Workbook()

    Dim path As String

    path = Application.StartupPath

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Value = path

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to creating a small method (as many have suggested), you can just use the immediate window (`View` | `Immediate Window` or <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> in the VBA editor) and enter:

```
? Application.StartupPath
```

The path will be written to the same window and you can copy and paste it into an Explorer window to navigate directly to the folder.

Answer (score -1):

the personal macros are stored in a .xlsb file, usually PERSONAL.XLSB
just use the Search function on your os drive (ie C:) and you will find it!

Comment: GIven how lame Windows 7 search is, just about anything would be a better answer. I told it to search `C:\Users\Dov\`--no matches. Then I told it to search `C:\Users\Dov\appdata` and it found matches. It's so unpredictable that I wrote my own search program.

Comment: @DSlomer64 I know what you mean.  Windows 9x had an excellent file search feature.  Since that time it has gone downhill.  Sometimes I've been known to resort to such things as the Find in Files feature of Notepad++ as a makeshift file search facility.  Admittedly this can't search by dates, and can be inefficient if the file is of significant size.

Something else that was best in Win9x and has gone downhill is the shutdown sequence.