# Delete macro that was saved wrong

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning EXCEL vba and was trying to create a macro that ran when EXCEL was opened.  It was saved as "Personal Workbook" and now every EXCEL spreadsheet I open has this macro.  Should have selected as "This Workbook". How do I get rid of that macro so that Workbooks open without it.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: [Where is the Excel Personal Macro Workbook Located?](http://wheatblog.com/2011/08/where-is-the-excel-personal-macro-workbook-located/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is your personal macro workbook located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183185/where-is-your-personal-macro-workbook-located)

Answer (score 1):

The personal workbook will be in Appdata/Microsoft/Excel/XLSTART. Just remove it from there. To get to your app data folder press windows+r and type %appdata%

Comment: Easy Peasy.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the module in Personal workbook that was created, rather than the whole file:

- In the *Visual Basic Editor* (`Alt + F11` to open)
- Find the `PERSONAL.XLSB` VBA Project in the *Project Explorer* (`Ctrl + R` to open in the VBE)
- Press the little `+` sign next to `VBAProject`.
- Press the little `+` sign next to the `Modules` folder in the project.
- Find the module containing the code, right-click the module and select *Remove ModuleName*

Answer (score 0):

Using the gui to get to the file.

In Excel

File -> Options

Click on "Customize Ribbon"

In the right hand pain there is a "Developer" checkbox that is unchecked by default, check it.

Now go to the "Developer" ribbon and click "Macros"

Click the macro you do not want an click "Delete".

Comment: FYI, If you  delete the file in Appdata/Microsoft/Excel/XLSTART you will lose all macros in your personal workbook.